# Dynamically format a float in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Consider this:

`NSString *whatever=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My float: %.2f",aFloat];`

This will round my `aFloat` to 2 decimal places when building the string `whatever`

Suppose I want the `2` in this statement to be assignable, such that, based on the value of `aFloat` I might have it show 2 or 4 decimal places. How can I build this into `stringWithFormat`?

I want to be able to do this without an `if` that simply repeats the entire line for different cases, but rather somehow dynamically change just the `%.2f` portion.

Comment: Just dynamically construct the string with a second `+stringWithFormat:` call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to build the format first:

```
NSInteger precision = 2;
NSString *format = [@"My float: %." stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", precision];
format = [format stringByAppendingString:@"f"];

NSString *whatever=[NSString stringWithFormat:format, aFloat];
```

Answer (score 11):

The proper answer is to use an NSNumberFormatter.

However, the easy answer that uses format strings is to use the asterisk specifier.  According to the [Apple documentatio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)n the format string conforms to the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). This specification states the following:

> A field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk ( '*' ). In this case an argument of type int supplies the field width or precision.

This means that

```
int precision = 2;
NSString *whatever=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My float: %.*f", precision,aFloat];
//                                   Asterisk in place of 2^^    ^^^^^^^^^ int variable
```

should work.  I have to say, I haven't tried it though, I tend to use NSNumberFormatters.

Answer (score 0):

Escape `%` as `%%` to build format strings:

```
NSUInteger digits = aFloat > 10.0f ? 2 : 4;
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My float: %%.%if", digits];
NSString *whatever = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, aFloat];
```