# Dynamically format a float in a NSString for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am having the same issues as here: [Dynamically format a float in a NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122210/dynamically-format-a-float-in-a-nsstring/35192001#35192001).

I have searched my hardest for the answer but everything I do seems to break it.

I have tried the following code:

```
cell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@km",[item objectForKey:@"distance"]];
```

the displayed value should only ever have two decimals but for some reason values between 1.00 and 9.99 display with more than two decimals.

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add the value of item dictionary?

Comment: Can you please provide some example, here like what would be input and what is required output for the same?

Comment: Convert your `NSString` into `CGFloat` then use `stringWithFormat` using `%.2f` which will print only till two decimals. Hope this helps.

Comment: @digitalElise forget all these aspergers developers downvoting this q, they dont remember what its like to be new. Just keep asking your questions, be specific and with time you will build rep around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to either use:

```
NSLog(@"THE LOG SCORE : %f", x);
```

OR you need to convert the float to a string like this:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat] stringValue];
```